# keep same radio button data in the next page

Tags: php, mysql

My main goal is to take 20 question from database for users to do and correct it. I am using MySQL query to fetch randomly 20 questions and display it on a page. Here is the code

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT `quiz_id`,`content`,`a`,`b`,`c`,`d` FROM quizzes ORDER BY rand() limit 20";   
$result = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);

echo '<form action="result.html" method="post"><div>';
$t = 0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)){
$t++;    
echo <<< EOF
<table>
<tr>

    <td>$t. $data[1]</td>
        </tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="a">$data[2]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="b">$data[3]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="c">$data[4]</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="option$data[0]" value="d">$data[5]</td></tr>

</table>
EOF;
}

    echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit" /></div></form>';
?>
```

Now i am implement the `result.php` page that will display again all the question that was random-ed from the first page and display result next to it. And i am stuck with the re-displaying the questions part. Any help would be much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You have to build on questions page your `checkboxes` inducing your `question.id` in inputs `name` and after submit save in session `'question_id'=>'answer yes|no'` values array, later on load of `result.php` take from session all input `'question_id'=>'answer yes|no'` pairs array and select from db all questions based on question id and display in front of it if it checked or no base on `'answer yes|no'` value

Answer (score 0):

Make a hidden field that contains comma separated id's of the questions you displayed on the page. On result.php, explode the hidden field that is posted from the previous page and loop through it to get the right answers.

```
<form action="result.html" method="post"><div>
<?php 
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)){

     $questions .= $data[0] . ','; // assume you have id in $data[0]
     // rest of your code
}
?>
<input name= 'question_ids' type='hidden' value= <?php echo $questions ?> />

</form>
```

**result.php**

```
$questions = explode(',' , $_POST['question_ids']);
foreach($questions as $question)
{
    // your logic here for getting right answer
}
```